# Reload a UITableView within a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, reloaddata

I am using MGTwitterEngine, and I have everthing working fairly smoothly. I am using it for an iPad program, and currently I have a UIView with a UITableView inside. I want to reload the table, but because I am using a UIViewController, I can't figure out how to target it. I understand the widely used method is:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

This doesn't work for me due to the projects hierarchy. I've tried targeting it like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [myTableview reloadData];
}
```

Or this..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [view.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas? This probably a very newbie question.

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, set up an IBOutlet you will connect to the tableview, it's that easy.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar problem, the problem was i was using "tabView" the name of my table, then when i used the self.tableView.datasource = self and [self.tableview reloaddata] it went correct.

Below link was for my problem..

[Reload tableview inside a UIview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604585/reload-tableview-inside-a-uiview?noredirect=1#comment43631393_27604585)