# Reload tableview inside a UIview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

My table view is inside a UI View, this has been done writing codes, now i am trying to reload the data in table view but the table view is not refreshing.

The UIview and the table view declaration are as follows:

```
@interface
{
 IBOutlet UITableView *tabView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet * tabView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView * myView;   // in .m file
```

Comment: Are you sure? did you put a breakpoint in numberOfRows method?

Comment: please provide the code.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Could it be a tableview connection problem, if yes then how?

Comment: did u assign the delegate/datasource to tableView.

Comment: please put the code you use to initialize view, table and to reload it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Provided you have linked up the delegate and the data source methods of the table view correctly, you could just do :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Make sure you have done :

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: this won't work since he hasn't declared a property for his UITableView. So `[tableView reloadData];` should work. Also dataSource can be set programmatically but he might aswell did it in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Yeah the problem was I was using "tabView" the name of my table, then when I used the self.tableView it went correct.

Comment: This was strange, why it dint happened with the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok there could be various mistakes which lead to your problem. First of all do you implement the datasource and delegate methods ?

To do so you should declare your header like this:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {}
```

Second you should hook up your tableView with those delegate/datasource methods. To do so drag&drop it in the InterfaceBuilder or in you `viewDidLoad` method write this:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Now make sure to implement all the necessary methods:

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {}
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {}
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

If you done all this you should update your tableView like so:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Also check if you connected your `IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;` in the Interface Builder.

Comment: There is nothing over the storyboard except the viewcontroller, all design I have done in code, how do I connect the tableview in this case?

Comment: Well then you don't have to connect it in a storyboard since you added your tableview via `[self.view addSubview:tableView];` right ? It would be easier to help you If you could provide some code you already tried ...